# Playing with String Functions

Tags: c, arrays, string

This is a very small question, and probably something really silly! But why am I getting garbage returned in my output for this function which should remove double letters?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char  *makehello( char *s ) {
   char new[16] ;
   int i ;
   int c = strlen(s);
   for ( i = 0; i < (c + 1); i++)
     if (toupper(s[i]) != toupper(s[i+1]))
       new[i] = toupper(s[i]);
return strdup( new ) ;  
}

int main(void) {
 char *new;
 char data[100];
 scanf("%s", data);
 new = makehello(data);
 printf("%s", new);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when there are more than 16 result letters?

Comment: Im just playing atm with aabb aacc etc to test it, but getting garbage printed :/

Comment: Make sure you terminate the result. Initialise it as `char new[16] = { 0 };`.

Comment: Still not making a difference

Comment: Im not getting any compiler warnings, just getting garbage printed. Not sure why at all though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a separate count for your 'new' array. You're storing them at index 'i' (where you found the character), but what you really want is to store them from position 0 and increment this count instead.

EDIT: Of course this isn't a fullproof method.

i.e something like this:

```
   for ( i = 0; i < c; i++)
   {
        if (toupper(s[i]) != toupper(s[i+1]))
        {
            new[count++]= toupper(s[i]);
        }
   }
   new[count] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
for ( i = 0; i < (c + 1); i++)
```

should be

```
for ( i = 0; i < (c - 1); i++)
```

And you then need before the `strdup` new[i]=0;

Braces would not go amise either.

**EDIT**

Forgot need to change the following

```
int i, j=0;
```

and in the for loop

```
new[j++] = toupper(s[i]);
```

and after the for loop

```
new[j] = 0;
```

Comment: Im still getting garbage output :/

Comment: i.e. bbb returns just garbage output

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reasonably compact C99 version of the algorithm (headers omitted, [example](http://ideone.com/k862O)):

```
const char * makehello (const char * s)
{
  char new[16] = { *s, 0 };
  const char * p = s;
  char c = *s, * q = new;

  while (*p) { if (*++p != c) { c = *++q = *p; } }

  return strdup(new) ;
}

int main(void)
 {
  char data[100];
  scanf("%s", data);
  printf("%s", makehello(data));
  return 0;
}
```

(This one discriminates case.)